# PHP: Can't print plaintext HTML

Tags: php, html

Weird issue.  I am new to PHP and am attempting something.  Here's my scenario:

HTML form... AJAX makes a call to a php script... PHP script calls WCF Web Service to get an array of objects.  What I want to do is create the raw HTML (which will be table row creation with the array of objects returned), pass that back to my HTML form and inject it into the desired table.

However, the data that is returned is not the raw HTML but a few tags and random numbers.  I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.  i've tried escape characters, using HTMLSpecialChars, etc but I keep coming back to the same problem.

```
    print htmlspecialchars("<tr>"
            . "<td>"
            . "<div class=\"row\">"
            . "<div style=\"float:right;width:50px\"><img src=\"" + $wsr->Article[$i]->ImageLink + "\" style=\"height: 50px\" /></div>"
            . "<div style=\"float:left;width:350px;\">"
            . "<div>"
            . "<h3 class=\"h3\" style=\"margin:0;\">" + $j + ". <a href=\"" + $wsr->Article[$i]->OriginLink + "\">" + $wsr->Article[$i]->HeadLine + "</a></h3>"
            . "<p class=\"p\" style=\"margin:0;\">" + $wsr->Article[$i]->Synopsis + "</p>"
            . "</div>"
            . "</div>"
            . "<div style=\"float:right; width:200px;padding-left:100px;\">"
            . "<input type=\"button\" value=\"yes\" id=\"btnyes" + $j + "\" /><input type=\"button\" value=\"No\" id=\"btnNo" + $j + "\" /><a href=\"URL\">" + $wsr->Article[$i]->ArticleCommentsAmount + " Comment(s)</a>\""
            . "</div>"
            . "</div>"
            . "</td>"
            . "</tr>");
```

What I get in return is:

```
    3</div></div></td></tr>6</div></div></td></tr>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. thank you.

Comment: Almost sounds like you're getting chunked encoding or something.  How exactly are you accessing this script?  Can you hit it with Fiddler, or post a packet trace?

Comment: just print without `htmlspecialchars()`, browser should turn it straight into a table.

Comment: Have you tried the function htmlentities? [Function htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: One suggestion is you can replace `\"` with single quotes(`'`)

Comment: @Brad I'm accessing the script through AJAX in JQuery:  $.post('Service.php', function(data){$("#mydiv > thead:last").append(data);});          I'm not sure what you're asking as far as Fiddler goes.  When I drag that php POST into the compose window, the response is just "html"

Comment: @jared Tried that at first but failed.  Still get that same response.

Comment: @Stegrex Tried that function but get an error about the it expecting a long string

Comment: @kmauzoul, The response you see in Fiddler... does it have headers as well?  Just the content is literally the 4 bytes `html`?  This is truly all of the code in your script?

Answer (score -1):

```
$string=htmlspecialchars("<tr>"
        . "<td>"
        . "<div class=\"row\">"
        . "<div style=\"float:right;width:50px\"><img src=\"" + $wsr->Article[$i]->ImageLink + "\" style=\"height: 50px\" /></div>"
        . "<div style=\"float:left;width:350px;\">"
        . "<div>"
        . "<h3 class=\"h3\" style=\"margin:0;\">" + $j + ". <a href=\"" + $wsr->Article[$i]->OriginLink + "\">" + $wsr->Article[$i]->HeadLine + "</a></h3>"
        . "<p class=\"p\" style=\"margin:0;\">" + $wsr->Article[$i]->Synopsis + "</p>"
        . "</div>"
        . "</div>"
        . "<div style=\"float:right; width:200px;padding-left:100px;\">"
        . "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Fan\" id=\"btnLike" + $j + "\" /><input type=\"button\" value=\"Not A Fan\" id=\"btnNotLike" + $j + "\" /><a href=\"URL\">" + $wsr->Article[$i]->ArticleCommentsAmount + " Comment(s)</a>\""
        . "</div>"
        . "</div>"
        . "</td>"
        . "</tr>");

 print($string);
```

Comment: This does nothing different than what was posted in the question.